# How to solve : $\,8^x=6x$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stuck on the following problem which one of my friends gave me:

> Solve : $\,8^x=6x$.

MY ATTEMPTS:

We see that $$8^x=6x \implies 2^{3x}=6x.$$ Now I am not sure how to proceed further. Taking logarithm on both sides of the equation does not help much. Clearly, $x=\frac 1 3$ satisfies the given equation but I am not sure how to get it.

Can someone help? Thanks and regards to all.

Comment: Well, the Lambert-W function might help here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function#Example_1 ?

Comment: I tried to solve this without using derivatives only to get frustrated. Oh well.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

For simplicity let $3x=u$ so you are really looking at $2^u = 2u$. One is exponential, the other is linear and given the nature of their derivatives, they intersect at most twice. In this case, they intersect twice: at $u=1$ and $u=2$. These are the only solutions. So for your original question that means $x = 1/3$ or $x=2/3$.

Comment: @learner The function $2^u$ has a strictly positive second derivative. Which means it will get steeper and steeper. It can intersect a linear function twice: once being less steep, and once being steeper. After that, $2^u$ will never "slow down" enough to intersect $2u$ again.

Answer (score 22):

In general, problems like this do not have closed-form solutions.  Taking the logarithm of this equation; you get:

$$
x\log 8 = \log x + \log 6
$$

Generalize this to

$$
ax + b\log x + c = 0
$$

If this had a solution algebraic in $a, b, c: x = A(a, b, c)$, then

$$
\begin{align}
aA + b\log A + c &= 0 \\
\log A &= -\frac{a}{b}A -\frac{c}{b} = B(a, b, c)\\
A(a, b, c) &= e^{B(a, b, c)}
\end{align}
$$

where both $A$ and $B$ are non-constant and algebraic in $a, b, c$.  That is impossible.

*I originally said that $\log x$ would be algebraic, and that isn't quite right.*

This problem was devised for effect.  We'll look backward here by seeing what happens if you substitute $y=3x$.

$$
\begin{align}
8^x &= 6x  \\
2^{3x} &=2 \cdot 3x\\
2^y &= 2y
\end{align}
$$

Now, we consider the *coincidence* that $2^2 = 2\cdot2$ and $2^1 = 2\cdot 1$.  So, $y=2$ and $y=1$ are solutions, and so $x=\frac23$ and $x=\frac13$ are solutions.  But for general constants, you can't hope to guess at a solution. You will be in the realm of numerical approximation.

Not understanding how to solve this problem is not a sign of a lack of skill. The problem is too contrived.

Comment: Thanks @Eric for the nice and detailed explanation. +1 from me.

Comment: Upvoted for that last sentence.

Comment: Nice solution Eric Jablow....

Answer (score 0):

Hint: How many different roots can this equation have?

Comment: Infinitely many, if you allow complex roots.

Comment: I know what you want to get at with your hint, but right now you are just rephrasing the question. Try to clarify, or else it's in trouble.

Comment: Right now the question is answered, so there is no need in hints. :-)

Answer (score 0):

$8^x=6x\implies e^{x\log 8}=6x\implies -xe^{-x\log8}\log8=-\dfrac{\log8}6$

Recall the Lambert W-function is defined as the inverse of $ze^z$ in $\Bbb C$, so if we let $t=-x\log8$, then $te^t=-\dfrac{\log8}6\implies t=W(-\dfrac{\log8}6)$

Hence, $x=-\dfrac{W(\dfrac{\log8}6)}{\log8}$.